# Adding items from one list to specific items of another list

Tags: python, list

Consider two lists:

`a = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]`

`b = [-10, 20, -88, 15, 10, -6, 10, 10]`

I wish to create a third list where each negative value from list `b` is replace with the corresponding (same index) item from list `a`. And then consecutively add the following positive numbers in list `b` to that replaced value (from list `a`), until the next negative number.

To clarify, the resulted list in the above case should be:

`c = [1000, 1020, 3000, 3015, 3025, 6000, 6010, 6020]`

my (working) code so far:

```
a = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]
b = [-10, 20, -88, 15, 10, -6, 10, 10]
c = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] < 0:
        c.append(a[i])
    else:
        c.append(c[-1]+b[i])
```

Is there a way to do so without a for loop? the lists can get very lengthy.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: What it is the current state of your code? Obviously you have a `for` loop somewhere?

Comment: I suggest you start by writing some code.

Comment: Thank you both. A working example using a for-loop is now edited into the question. Looking for a nicer way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by nicer? This for loop seems very clean and obvious about what it does. You're going to have to iterate over the full list no matter what, so I don't think a for loop is any less efficient than any other solution would be.

Comment: I was wondering if any faster solutions are possible.

Comment: Your code crashes when `b` starts with a positive number. Is it guaranteed that `b` always starts with a negative number?

Comment: Are the entries in list `a` always going to be increments of 1000 line that? If so, you don't need list `a` at all; you can just compute the value based on the index as you iterate over list `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I used zip to go through both of the list, in this case with the assumption that both lengths are equal. Should be able to work for most cases as long it is.

```
a = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000]
b = [-10, 20, -88, 15, 10, -6, 10, 10]

c = []

old_val = 0
for value_a,value_b in zip(a,b):
    print(value_b)
    if value_b < 0:
        c.append(value_a)
        old_val = value_a
    else:
        old_val += value_b
        c.append(old_val)

#[1000, 1020, 3000, 3015, 3025, 6000, 6010, 6020]
```